# Log4j configuration for spring MVC app on Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, log4j

I've been developing a simple Spring MVC application as a reporting service.  Locally, I've been running the application with the maven-tomcat-plugin, using `mvn tomcat:run`.  This works exactly as expected.  However, I'm now trying to deploy this service to a server running Tomcat 6.  I load the war file into the webapps directory, Tomcat notices it, deploys it, and then complains:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
(org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter).

log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

And, unsurprisingly, no logging for the service works.

This above error message isn't clear to me, and I wonder if anyone could give me some assistance.

For posterity, I have a very simple log4j.properties file (Which lives in `/src/main/resources`):

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, console

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern= %d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %-5p %x %C{1} : %m%n

log4j.logger.com.rtr=DEBUG
```

My current hypothesis is that the tomcat box might not be seeing this property bundle at all, but I'm not sure.  I was able to confirm this hypothesis by hot-copying the bundle into `WEB-INF/classes`, and getting an appropriate result.  What is the correct location that is both on the classpath, but not in a strange location?

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Have you confirmed the properties file is in `/WEB-INF/classes` in the war file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven copies the resource files from `/src/main/resources` to `/WEB-INF/classes` during the `compile` phase of the mvn lifecycle.  Using the command `mvn war:war` will NOT copy these resources, so you must do `mvn compile war:war` for the resources to be available to your application.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the `log4j.properties` file needs to be in the class path if you want it to be picked up automatically. I usually place it in the Tomcat's Lib folder or the war's lib folder.

Comment: I tried putting it in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib`, but it didn't seem to work, so continuing down this path (which definitely smells a little to me), I hot-copied the bundle into the `WEB-INF/classes/` dir.  When I did this, tomcat found the bundle just fine.  Weird?

Comment: Directories in the src tree are not in the class path in the WAR file.

Comment: @DwB It's a Maven project; resources in `/src/main/resources` are copied into the class directory.